# .htaccess rules 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

using this: http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php

I made to rewrite

```
www.example.com/index.php?p=page
```

to

```
www.example.com/page
```

for some reason this gives 500 Internal Server Error, regardless of I visit:

- `www.example.com`
- `www.example.com/page`
- `www.example.com/index.php?p=page`

rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Check your server's error log. The cause for the error will be in there. You're most likely missing the overrides required (ie `FileInfo`) to use the `mod_rewrite` directives (or `mod_rewrite` isn't actually enabled)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?p=$1 [L]
> ```

This will result in a rewrite loop (hence your 500 error). One way to prevent a rewrite loop is by checking that the URL doesn't already contain a `p` URL param before attempting to rewrite. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^p=
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

Comment: How does this create a loop? The `L` flag should prevent that from happening

Comment: In `.htaccess` the `L` flag just stops the current round of processing. The process starts again and continues until the URL passes through unchanged.

Comment: But this is an internal rewrite. There isn't another request made. I think you need to test your assumptions

Comment: Just tested on my server and it **does not** result in a redirect loop

Comment: @Phil Are you testing this as written, with a slash prefix on the _substitution_? This certainly results in a "Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects..." for me (I suspect because of the URL, as opposed to filesystem path?) - note that this is an "internal" rewrite loop, not an _external_ "redirect loop". As you say, there "isn't another request". The "infinite" rewrite loop can be avoided by removing the slash prefix (allowing the directory-prefix to be added back - now a filesystem path), but this still results in two rewrites which effectively "breaks" the request...

Comment: @Phil For example, _without the slash prefix_, a request for `/test` gets rewritten to `index.php?p=test`, which gets rewritten to `index.php?p=index.php`, which is obviously not the desired result. If, however, the slash prefix is included (as in the above) then the process appears to continue, trying to rewrite to the same URL `/index.php?p=index.php` forever, ...until the server breaks with "Request exceeded the limit..."

Answer (score -1):

needed to add a / so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/([^/]*)$ /index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

Comment: In `.htaccess` adding a slash to the start of the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ won't "fix" the problem, it just makes the error go away - because this now won't do anything.